# How to wrap array of html span tags with more span tags?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I made a component that wraps every letter of my text in a span tag:

```
export default function Header({ text }) {
    let header = []

    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        const colours = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "pink", "orange"]
        const rng = Math.floor((Math.random() * colours.length))

        header.push({
            color: colours[rng],
            letter: text.charAt(i) == ' ' ? <span className="white-space"></span> : text.charAt(i)
        })
    }

    return (
        <h1 id="header">
            {header.map((el, i) => (<span key={i} style={{ color: el.color }}>{el.letter}</span>))}
        </h1>
    )
}
```

which will produce this result (where text is "Hello World"):

```
<h1 id="header">
    <span>H</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span><span className="white-space"></span></span>
    <span>W</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>d</span>
</h1>
```

It works well, but when the size of the sentence is larger than the size of the browser window, it will wrap some letters which sometimes messes up the entire text (instead of "Hello World" you could get "Hello", "Wo", "rld").

To fix this I now need to wrap groups of span tags that are words in additional span tags, to reach this result:

```
<h1 id="header">
    <span>
        <span>H</span>
        <span>e</span>
        <span>l</span>
        <span>l</span>
        <span>o</span>
    </span>
    <span><span className="white-space"></span></span>
    <span>
        <span>W</span>
        <span>o</span>
        <span>r</span>
        <span>l</span>
        <span>d</span>
    </span>
</h1>
```

How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change text into an array of strings. Then loop over the words and split them into characters:

```
export default function Header({ words = ["hello", "world"] }) {
  const header = words.map((word, j) => {
    return (
      <>
        <span>
          {word.split("").map((letter, i) => {
            const colours = [
              "red",
              "green",
              "yellow",
              "blue",
              "pink",
              "orange",
            ];
            const rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);

            return (
              <span key={i} style={{ color: colours[rng] }}>
                {letter}
              </span>
            );
          })}
        </span>
        {j < words.length - 1 && <span className="white-space"></span>}
      </>
    );
  });

  return <h1 id="header">{header}</h1>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Improvised version:

```
function wrapLetters(word) {
  const wrappedLetters = [];
  const colours = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "pink", "orange"];
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    const rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
    wrappedLetters.push(
      <span key={i} style={{ color: colours[rng] }}>
        {word[i]}
      </span>
    );
  }
  return wrappedLetters;
}

function wrapWord(wrappedLetters, i, notLast) {
  return (
    <span className="wrapper" key={i}>
      {notLast
        ? [...wrappedLetters, <span className="white-space" />]
        : wrappedLetters}
    </span>
  );
}

export default function Header({ text }) {
  const words = text.split(" ");
  const wrappedWords = words
   .map(wrapLetters)
   .map((wrappedLetters, i) => {
     return wrapWord(wrappedLetters, i, i < words.length - 1);
   });
  return <h1 id="header">{wrappedWords}</h1>;
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-sea-lvg6x?file=/src/Component.js:0-871

---

I wrote the component like this. Hope the comments are self explianatory.

```
function wrapWord(word) {
  const lettersData = [];
  const colours = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "pink", "orange"];
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    const rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
    lettersData.push(
      <span key={i} style={{ color: colours[rng] }}>
        {word[i]}
      </span>
    );
  }
  return lettersData;
}

export default function Header({ text }) {
  const words = text.split(" "); // split text into an array if words
  const wordsData = words.map((word) => wrapWord(word)); // for each word create an array of spans

  // this method wraps each word with a span, and injects a space if it's not last word
  const combinedWords = wordsData.map((arr, i) => {
    return (
      <span className="wrapper" key={i}>
        {i < wordsData.length - 1
          ? [...arr, <span className="white-space" />]
          : arr}
      </span>
    );
  });

  return <h1 id="header">{combinedWords}</h1>;
}
```

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-hugle-6xpud?file=/src/Component.js:0-739